# Unordered List Alignment - Products Side by Side

Tags: html, css

At my wits end. Have looked at other answered questions on here, and can't seem to get the answers to work.

My fiddle: (Exp:resso store code left in just to show that that's what I'm using.)

https://jsfiddle.net/4gk5qszm/

HTML:

```
<div class="StoreContent-Index">
{exp:store:search orderby="date" sort="desc"}
{exp:store:product entry_id="{entry_id}"}

<ul class="StoreContent-ProductIndexList">
<li>
<a href="{url_title_path='store/product'}">
<img src="{product_image}" class="TCBProductImgCat">
<h4>{title}</h4>
<p>{regular_price}</p>
</a>
</li>
</ul>

{/exp:store:product}
{/exp:store:search}
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList{
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  float: left;
}

ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList li {
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
}

.StoreContent-Index{
background: #FFF;
width: 100%;
}

.StoreContent-ProductIndexList:after { 
clear: both;
}
```

How it looks live:

http://www.thymecher.com/0316-S

I've tried grid alignment, floating, all the inline stuff - nada. I just want the danged things to align properly side by side in the list style shown in the fiddle. (Image, title underneath, price underneath that - repeated horizontally, not vertically, with - say - 8 products per line.)

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your live site seems rather different from the code you posted. The `ul`s are wrapped in `form`s. For it to work you could add `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top` to `.store_product_form`. As for your fiddle, I didn't observe anything _not_ being inline (see https://jsfiddle.net/4gk5qszm/1/). Could you post your rendered HTML (instead of the Expression template)?

Comment: As @AndrewMyers points out, the code on your site doesn't actually match what you've posted and the markup on your site is pretty wacky, semantically. Since this is a WP-based store, I'm assuming you don't control a lot of this markup, like the div full of hidden inputs in each form element or the `.StoreContent-ProductIndexList` lists. I'm working on a fix now, but if you have the capacity to change some of this markup, things will be a lot cleaner/easier.

Comment: Thanks for taking a look! I posted is EXACTLY what I coded in my templates; however, what you're speaking of is apparently being rendered from the Exp:resso Store mod, which I don't have the first clue as to where to look to edit that. Where I'm displaying categories rather than the products IN the categories, I have a grid layout going & it works great, but applying it to the prods hasn't worked - thus, my stop here for help. :) This is an EXPRESSION ENGINE based store, not WP. :) You're right, I definitely don't control the markup...

Comment: And I should add that my attempts to contact the author of the plugin have been futile. :( I appreciate anything you have to offer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as Andrew pointed out, your example code doesn't really match what's happening on your site. Within the `.StoreContent-Index` div, every one of your products is wrapped in a `form` element and, within that is a `div` and a `ul`, the latter of which has the actual product info in it.

The combination of `form` elements being block-level elements and the fact that many basic HTML elements have a default clearfix ([What is clearfix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8554043/what-is-clearfix)) applied to them in your stylsheet was really working against you here. I have a working, minimal example on [CodePen](http://codepen.io/angeliquejw/pen/jqwqGX?editors=1100) that you can review, but assuming you can make changes to all of your stylesheets, the main changes you'll want to make will be in http://www.thymecher.com/?css=0316-Styles/store-main.v.1458927906

In that stylesheet, you can remove the following code:

```
ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList{
  display: inline-block;
  *display: inline;
  zoom: 1;
  float: left;
}

ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList li {
width: 200px;
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
*display: inline;
*zoom: 1;
}
```

and replace it with this:

```
ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList, ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList > li {
  list-style:none;
}
.store_product_form {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
  width: 200px;
}
```

This should give you the layout you're looking for.

Comment: Angelique, thank you! I'll go attempt that right now & report back. Cross your fingers! :)

Comment: Angelique, you are amazing, and I can't thank you enough. This is EXACTLY what I was going for. THANK YOU!! (And everyone else that replied as well! :) )

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle not rendering correctly.

I don't think your CSS naming conventions are valid

> ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList li

You should just use the StoreContent-ProductIndexList class; or

> .StoreContent-ProductIndexList li

I would research FlexBox.  It really helps with alignment (someone's CodePen example: http://codepen.io/HugoGiraudel/pen/LklCv).
    .StoreContent-ProductIndexList {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: space-around;
    }

You may want to give your "li" lines a class name too

```
.liClasses {
  margin: as needed;
  others: as needed;
}
```

Comment: The selector `ul.StoreContent-ProductIndexList li` is a perfectly valid CSS selector. You can verify that it works either with DevTools, or by adding the rule `background: red;` on jsFiddle and observing what gets colored.